# Template class that takes a template class as template won't compile

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to make a class that takes a map as a template parameter. In particular it should be able to take std::map and boost::ptr_map. Currently I'm trying this:

```
template <template<typename, typename> class MAP, typename KEYTYPE, typename DATATYPE>
class RestrictedMapBase
{
   /* bunch of methods ... */
}
```

This class is being inherited by two other classes, one for std::map and one for boost::ptr_map.

```
template <typename KEYTYPE, typename DATATYPE>
class RestrictedMap: public RestrictedMapBase<std::map, KEYTYPE, DATATYPE>
{
   /* Bunch of methods ... */
};

template <typename KEYTYPE, typename DATATYPE>
class RestrictedPointerMap: public RestrictedMapBase<boost::ptr_map, KEYTYPE, DATATYPE>
{
   /* Bunch of methods ... */
};
```

But on compilation I get these errors:

> RestrictedMap.h(166) : error C3201: the template parameter list for
>   class template 'std::map' does not match the template parameter list
>   for template parameter 'MAP'    RestrictedMap.h(183) : see reference
>   to class template instantiation
>   'STLUtils::RestrictedMap' being compiled
>
> RestrictedMap.h(186) : error C3201: the template parameter list for
>   class template 'boost::ptr_map' does not match the template parameter
>   list for template parameter 'MAP'    RestrictedMap.h(203) : see
>   reference to class template instantiation
>   'STLUtils::RestrictedPointerMap' being compiled

Can anybody point me in the right direction of what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class template `std::map` have 4 arguments:

```
template <typename _Key, typename _Tp, typename _Compare = std::less<_Key>,
          typename _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> > >
class map
```

Thus it can not be pass via `template<typename, typename>` just like you can not assign a pointer to a 3-argument function to a pointer to 2-argument function.

The solution is to pass the exact type to use to `RestrictedMapBase`:

```
template <typename MAP>
class RestrictedMapBase
{
   typedef typename MAP::key_type KEYTYPE;
   typedef typename MAP::mapped_type DATATYPE;
};
```

Your initial design also limits users of your class because they can not specify a compare function for keys (or a hash function if they want to use hash tables) and an allocator.

Comment: I accepted this as the answer because it handles the error I made. Even though I used Mark Ingram's answer to fix my problem.

Answer (score 1):

std::map expects a template parameter to define what it is a map of. See below:

```
template <typename KEYTYPE, typename DATATYPE>
class RestrictedMap: public RestrictedMapBase<std::map<KEYTYPE, DATATYPE>, KEYTYPE, DATATYPE>
{
   /* Bunch of methods ... */
};
```

Your base class template parameters `KEYTYPE` and `DATATYPE` then become redundant. You can replace those with the typedefs provided in std::map's class:

```
std::map<_Kty, _Ty>::key_type; // This is the same as KEYTYPE
std::map<_Kty, _Ty>::mapped_type; // This is the same as DATATYPE
```

I would re-write your class something like this (I haven't tested this):

```
template <typename Map>
class RestrictedMap
{
public: // Typedefs
    typedef typename Map::key_type KeyType;
    typedef typename Map::mapped_type MapType;

public: // Methods
    // TODO: Write your methods here.
    void Add(const KeyType &key, const MapType &map);

private: // Members
    Map m_map;
};
```

Then you could choose your map like this (again un-tested):

```
typedef RestrictedMap<std::map<int, int>> StlMap; // TODO: Change your map's key and data type
typedef RestrictedMap<boost::ptr_map<int, int>> BoostMap; // TODO: Change your map's key and data type
```

Full example available here - http://ideone.com/U3AkV

Comment: Why have you shown me a code example for the OP's original code? My code compiles: http://ideone.com/U3AkV